# Issue in printing iFrame in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iframe like

```
<iframe id="Frame1" name="Frame1" style="width: 810px;overflow:hidden;height:525px;border:none;"src="templates/template1.html">
</iframe>
```

When I click generate button
the generate function will call.In generate function i changed the src of the iframe to template2.html.

```
    <input type="button"  id="btngenerate" onclick="Generate();"/>
    <a id="print" onclick="OnPrint();">Print</a>
```

When I click on the print link after clicking the generate button,I want to print the iframe.

```
    function generate()
    {
        var billPath = "templates/template2.html";
        $("#Frame1").attr("src", billPath);
    }

    function onPrint()
    {
        window.frames["Frame1"].window.focus();
        window.frames["Frame1"].window.print(); 
    }
```

It works in Firefox. But not in chrome. 
In chrome the template1.html will be printed.I want to print template2.html.
When I call `window.print();` it will print the whole page.
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use a separate window to print your content (like I described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281929/701869) ?