# Chrome and Firefox not printing contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I am having an issue when I go to print a page in chrome and firefox, it is not printing the content of an iframe on my page (works in IE, weird right).  The only way I've discovered so far that I can print it in those browsers, is if I click in the iframe and do ctrl + a to select all, and then print, it will print only the content of the iframe (which works for me).

The chrome version:  Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The firefox version: 54.0 (32-bit)

I have tried to give focus to the iframe and print it, but have no success so far doing:

```
window.frames["myFrameId"].focus();
window.frames["myFrameId"].print();
```

Would anybody have a recommendation of how can I simulate the crtl + a functionality inside the iframe or another way to print the whole page in these browsers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258079/issue-in-printing-iframe-in-google-chrome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648594/print-iframe-content-in-opera-and-chrome